# Return to mainview from subview

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4

Basically I want to remove my subview when a button is pressed, here is my code, please tell me what should I add.

I have created a view based application and following are the codes:

//My file name is poo1

**//This is poo1ViewController.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface poo1ViewController : UIViewController 
{
 IBOutlet UIButton *fl;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *fl;
-(IBAction) ifl:(id)sender;    
@end
```

**This is poo1ViewController.m file**

```
    #import "poo1ViewController.h"
    @implementation poo1ViewController
    @synthesize fl;
    -(IBAction) ifl:(id) sender {
    UIViewController* flipViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"flip" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.view addSubview:flipViewController.view];
    }
```

Now similarly I have added a UIViewController Subclass called "flip" with xib. **And in flip.h I have added the below code**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface flip : UIViewController 
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *bb;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain)UIButton *bb;
-(IBAction)ss:(id)sender;
@end
```

**And in flip.m**

```
#import "flip.h"
@implementation flip
@synthesize bb;

-(IBAction)ss:(id)sender
{
 //What do I need to add here to return to previous view when button is pressed.
}
```

***When this bb button is pressed, it should act as back button, how to implement it.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add `[self removeFromSuperview];` to your method `ss:`
Note however that this does not dealloc the view from the memory. It's just not showing!

Comment: It shows warning and says "flip may not respond to removeFromSuperview

Comment: ok... try changing parent class of flip from controller to view @interface flip : UIView

Comment: It is already UIView, I have uploaded the project here: http://cl.ly/8Hk0 . Can you please look into it and point out my mistake and edit the program and upload again. Will be highly obliged if you do so.

Comment: Ok..the solution is write [self.view removeFromSuperview]; in the method ss:(id)sender. I think you should not extend the UIViewController for the pp class. You can just use a UIView. It seems you are beginning with iOS so this was a good exercise for you.Try doing the same thing with UIView...

Comment: And ya, by doing this [self.view removeFromSuperview]; will it dealloc the view from memory

Comment: Can we implement the same thing in Table view, if I select a cell in tableview which in turn loads another view, if keep a button their and use the same  [self.view removeFromSuperview]; can I come to table view back again?

Comment: removeFromSuperview does'nt dealloc the view.

Comment: and of course you can implement this in a table view but a better way would be to use a navigation controller and pushing the next view onto this controller's view. That way you would be automatically provided with a back button on the navigation bar with complete functionality! Read more about it on iOS developer guide...

Comment: but I want to use swipe gestures to go back to table view, that's why I don't want to use navigation control. Now, after I have implemented swipe gestures, it is simply not responding to any gestures in table view[when I open any cell, i can't use swipe gestures to return back to table view]

Comment: u mean like using swipe gestures on home screen to change the page? For that, you can use 'page control'.

Comment: No I am not talking about that.
I am explaining my issue here below:

I have a tableview which has 3 cells named a,b and c.
When I click on 'a' it opens another view, now I want to swipeleft to right so that it returns back to tableview.

This is what I want to implement but I am unable to

Comment: hmm...you'll have to use swipe gestures or the {-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event } methods to pop view controller when the user makes a swipe gesture

Comment: I have done it, but it is of no use. When I swipe it doesn't respond. Should I upload the file and will you just look into it.

Comment: I have uploaded my project here: http://cl.ly/8ZlP . Please look into the code and tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: The emer1ViewController.m file is missing! Anyway, try to use [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; in touchesMoved: method of f1.m. Also, this is a different problem from the current one so you must ask another question so that others can also contribute to this.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but can you please look into the code http://cl.ly/8a5g [updated]. It doesn't work even with [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; .

Can you just edit the code and upload it with correct code, will highly be grateful to you. And can you tell how can I remove the second view out of memory not just only hide it.

Thanks from ahead, for helping this student.

Comment: The problem was that you needed a navigation controller in your app delegate. I've uploaded the updated project at http://cl.ly/1x2X2r2l2s0Z3Y001b13

Comment: dude ,I'm also a beginner...and judging by your name, we're fellow countrymen!!